# Show/hide div based on time of day jquery

Tags: jquery, time, range, hide, show

I've got some code that I thought should work to show or hide two divs depending on the time of day.  It currently shows the "closed" div despite the time being later than it is - am I missing anything? The website is running on only two machines so it only needs to get the time set on them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

if (time > ("08:29") && time < ("16:29")) {
    $('.hours').show();
    $('.closed').hide();
}
else {
    $('.hours').hide();
    $('.closed').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: As per your need, condition you have written is incorrect. You have to check hours and minutes individually

Comment: Sorry how do I do that?

Comment: @mickbale check my answer below, I explained how to do that

Comment: I have added my answer below, with small demo in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var time = new Date();
```

add two variables:

```
var startTime = new Date().setHours(8,29);
var endTime = new Date().setHours(16,29);
```

And in `if` statement use this expression

```
if (time.getTime() > startTime && time.getTime() < endTime) {
```

Comment: Scratch my last comment, error on my part - this did the job, thanks for your help!  In all the examples I'd seen of using time they never showed how to set one, but makes sense not to set it as a string - doh!

Answer (score 0):

`getHours()` and `getMinutes()` on the date object doesn't zero pad. So if it's 08:03, that'll be 8:3.

Perhaps look into using MomentJS where you can call `format` on a date and parse it to the desired format.

Edit: as a quick fix, use `d.toISOString().split('T')[1]`

Comment: Oh right.  I would have thought it would be a standard thing. Hmm, even if I take the 0 off "08:29" it doesn't work.  I'll take a look at MomentJS, cheers.

Comment: Look at @DicBrus answer, that will do the trick and won't need momentjs

Answer (score 0):

You don't compare the time using strings. You need two date objects to compare them.

The easier way is to create two more dates and set the time on them based on low and high time limits. Then compare your source time with the limits.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var d = new Date();
  var low = new Date();
  var high = new Date();

  low.setHours(8);
  low.setMinutes(29);
  high.setHours(16);
  high.setMinutes(29);

  if (d.getTime() > low.getTime() && d.getTime() < high.getTime()) {
    $('.hours').show();
    $('.closed').hide();
  } else {
    $('.hours').hide();
    $('.closed').show();
  }
});
```

[`Date#getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns the number of milliseconds, which is easier to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared demo for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/52387/), in which we will be doing like

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
var time = new Date().getTime();

if (time > start.setHours(8,29) && time < end.setHours(16,29))
```